# Using jQuery Datatable's fnFooterCallback after adding data using fnAddData

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get the total of my Totals column placed in the footer using "fnFooterCallback" but I'm not having any luck and I keep getting the "Cannot reinitialise Datatable" warning on me.

Here is my HTML code:

```
        <table id="hours" border="1" class="display dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Order Number
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Machine
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Start
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Stop
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Total
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Edit
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                    
            </tbody>   
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Total:
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

any my jQuery code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    // add the data to the tbody
    var oTable = $("#hours").dataTable().fnAddData([
                                    item[i].OrderNumber,
                                    item[i].MachineName,
                                    item[i].startTime,
                                    item[i].stopTime,
                                    item[i].totalTime,
                                    item[i].editButton
                                ]);

}
// after the data is added, get the total of the Totals Column
oTable = $("#hours").dataTable(  
    {
        "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
                 var total = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < aaData.length; i++) {
                            total += aaData[i][4] * 1;
                        }

                        var page = 0;
                        for (var i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
                            page += aaData[aiDisplay[i]][4] * 1;
                        }

                        /* Modify the footer row to match what we want */
                        var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                        nCells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(page);
        }
        });
```

I know creating a second call to dataTable is my problem, but I'm not sure how else to call the "fnFooterCallback" after I've added data using dnAddData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out.

I had it backwards.  I needed to initialize the table first and use fnFooterCallback while assigning it to a variable.

```
var oTable = $("#hours").dataTable(  
    {
        "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
                 var total = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < aaData.length; i++) {
                            total += aaData[i][4] * 1;
                        }

                        var page = 0;
                        for (var i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
                            page += aaData[aiDisplay[i]][4] * 1;
                        }

                        /* Modify the footer row to match what we want */
                        var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                        nCells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(page);
        }
        });
```

and then add the data by chaining the fnAddData call to the variable

```
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    // add the data to the tbody
    oTable.fnAddData([
                       item[i].OrderNumber,
                       item[i].MachineName,
                       item[i].startTime,
                       item[i].stopTime,
                       item[i].totalTime,
                       item[i].editButton
                     ]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the callback `fnCreateRow` and keep the total in a public variable.

```
"fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
}
```

However, why don't you use the "items" as data source instead of adding to the table?
You are trying to initialize the table twice.

```
$("#hours").dataTable();
oTable = $("#hours").dataTable({});
```

Comment: He is initializing `item.length +1` times actually. God know how many times that is.

Comment: Sure...item.length + n